Example of a non-zero compact Toeplitz operator with bounded symbol on the Bergman space $\mathbb A^2 \left (\mathbb D \right ).$
I am looking for an example of a non-zero compact Toeplitz operator with bounded symbol on the Bergman space $\mathbb A^2 \left (\mathbb D \right ).$ Could anyone provide me one such?
Thanks a lot.

My knowledge in this topic is limited. Are you looking for $\varphi \in A^2(D)$ such that $T_\varphi$ is compact ?

@RyszardSzwarc$:$ No, I want $\varphi \in L^{\infty} \left (\mathbb D \right )$ such that $T_{\varphi}$ is compact as an operator from $\mathbb A^2 \left (\mathbb D \right )$ to itself.
